# Calling JSONP webservice with C# in Windows Phone application

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I'm trying to build a Windows Phone 7.1 application in which I need to make a call to a jsonp webservice. Any idea how I might try to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to make the call to the JSONP service directly using an HttpWebRequest - the call will typically be a simple GET or POST. Example code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/156610/WP7-WebClient-vs-HttpWebRequest

For parsing the results, you will probably need to remove the JSONP wrapper (it is just a function call normally) and will then be able to parse the results using a JSON parser - e.g. JSON.Net - see http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: I got the first part working, using the code in the link in your first paragraph. Also downloaded JSON.NET and now I need to figure out how to remove the JSONP wrapper.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP - basically you'll just need to convert: `functionCall({"Name": "Foo", "Id" : 1234, "Rank": 7});` into `{"Name": "Foo", "Id" : 1234, "Rank": 7}` - shouldn't be too hard using string methods or using Regex